# How to use Sum method conditionally in Select section in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have following query:

```
var query = from comment in SH_Comments
        join user in Users
        on comment.UserID equals user.UserID

        join product in SH_Products
        on comment.ProductID equals product.ID

        join vote in SH_CommentVotes
        on comment.ID equals vote.CommentID

        group comment by new
        {
            comment.Body,
            comment.CreatedDate,
            comment.IsApproved,
            comment.IsRead,
            comment.ID,
            comment.ProductID,
            comment.UserID,
            comment.ParentID,
            user.DisplayName,
            user.Username,
            product.Title,
            vote.IsPositive
        } into g

        select new
        {
            g.Key.Body,
            g.Key.CreatedDate,
            g.Key.IsApproved,
            g.Key.IsRead,
            g.Key.ID,
            g.Key.ProductID,
            g.Key.UserID,
            g.Key.ParentID,
            g.Key.DisplayName,
            g.Key.Username,
            g.Key.Title,
            PositiveVotes = g.Where(c=>g.Key.IsPositive).Sum(c=>g.Key.ID),
            NegativeVotes = g.Where(c=>!g.Key.IsPositive).Sum(c=>g.Key.ID)
        };
```

I want to get `PositiveVotes` and `NegativeVotes` count, by IsPositive field in my table.
If my way is wrong, could you please tell me the true way?

I got following error on it:
`Column 't4.Body' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

How I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: (I think you might want to `Count` the votes instead of `Sum` the `ID`s.)

Answer (score 1):

I got the true way, so I put my way here for you guys !

```
var query = from comment in SH_Comments
        join user in Users
        on comment.UserID equals user.UserID

        join product in SH_Products
        on comment.ProductID equals product.ID

        join vote in SH_CommentVotes
        on comment.ID equals vote.CommentID

        group comment by new
        {
            comment.Body,
            comment.CreatedDate,
            comment.IsApproved,
            comment.IsRead,
            comment.ID,
            comment.ProductID,
            comment.UserID,
            comment.ParentID,
            user.DisplayName,
            user.Username,
            product.Title,
            vote.IsPositive
        } into g

        select new
        {
            g.Key.Body,
            g.Key.CreatedDate,
            g.Key.IsApproved,
            g.Key.IsRead,
            g.Key.ID,
            g.Key.ProductID,
            g.Key.UserID,
            g.Key.ParentID,
            g.Key.DisplayName,
            g.Key.Username,
            g.Key.Title,
            PositiveVotes = g.Where(c=>g.Key.IsPositive).Count(),
            NegativeVotes = g.Where(c=>!g.Key.IsPositive).Count()
        };      

var list = query
        .GroupBy(x => new
        { 
            x.Title,
            x.Body,
            x.CreatedDate,
            x.IsApproved,
            x.IsRead,
            x.ID,
            x.ProductID,
            x.UserID,
            x.ParentID,
            x.DisplayName,
            x.Username,

        })
        .Select(x => new 
        { 
            x.Key.Body,
            x.Key.CreatedDate,
            x.Key.IsApproved,
            x.Key.IsRead,
            x.Key.ID,
            x.Key.ProductID,
            x.Key.UserID,
            x.Key.ParentID,
            x.Key.DisplayName,
            x.Key.Username,
            x.Key.Title,
            PositiveVotes = x.Sum(s => s.PositiveVotes),
            NegativeVotes = x.Sum(s => s.NegativeVotes) 
        });
```

Thanks to `Gábor Bakos` for his great comment.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for bringing it together. I have started something similar as an answer too, but it was too long. I am glad you did. :)